# Search through multiple models in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I created models for a listing website. 
Here is my models

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    .....

class Address(models.Model):
    listing =  models.OneToOneFielSo, d(Listing, related_name='address')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    postcode = models.IntegerField()
    lat = models.FloatField("Latitude")
    lng = models.FloatField("Longitude")
    ....
```

So, I want to user able to search the listing through the 'tags', 'lat' and 'lng'. The 'tags' is as the keywords, and 'lat lng' for the reference point for certain range.
Eg: search for 'House' (keyword) in 5KM range from your place (lat, lng) where 'type 'is 'for rent'.

The problem here is there are  3 models involve in the search. I have no idea how to start. 
What I thinking is writing a html form that:

```
<form method="get" action="/search/">
<label>Keyword</label><input type="text" name="q" value="">
<label>Range</label><input type="text" name="r" value="">
<label>Type</label><input type="text" name="t" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="{{lat, lng}}">//get from browser
</form>
```

In my view.py

```
def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get("q")
    r = request.GET.get("r")
    t = request.GET.get("t")
    p = request.GET.get("p")
    range = calculate_range(p)#method to calculate the range
    filter = Listing.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[q], status=t, 
            address__lat__range=(range.lat.start, range.lat.end),
            address__lng__range=(range.lng.start, range.lng.end))
   ......
```

Is this a correct way to do so?? I think there are have better way to do it. But I don't know how. Do you need to create the search form from form.py or hard coded like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using class-based views, you can use FormView. Take look: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: Can you elaborate more? The documentation has only little of details. I want to know how do I display the form across the website, how to get the user lat and lang in the model..etc.

Comment: In you FormView(s), form_class = YourFrom will make the form available. Using the queryset argument you can specify data.

Comment: No problem. If the answer satisfied you, mark it as answered.

Comment: The URL gives a 404 as of the date I write this comment.